# The user stays logged in even if logged out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm running this code in **API > routes > `Auth.js`** (Letting the user Log In using google Auth), but the problem if I logged the user out and refresh the page it get logged in again by itself!

```
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { 
  scope: ["email", "profile"] }));

router.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google", {
  successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/",
  failureRedirect: "/login/failed"
}));

router.get("/googleLogin/success", async (req, res)=>{
  if(req.user){
    const user = await User.findOne({provider_id: req.user.id, 
      provider: req.user.provider})
    if(user){
       res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "success",
        user: user
      })
    }else{
      const checkUserEmail = await User.findOne({email: req.user.email})
      if(checkUserEmail){
        res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          message: "User already Exist with this email id",
        })
      }else{
        const user = await User.create({
          username: req.user.name.givenName+ "_" +req.user.name.familyName,
          email: req.user.emails[0].value,
          provider: req.user.provider,
          provider_id: req.user.id
        });
         res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: "success",
          user: user
        })
      }
    }
    console.log("CURRNT USER: ", user);
  }
})

router.get("/login/failed", (req, res)=>{
  if(req.user){
    res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "failure",
    })
  }
})

router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout(); req.session = null;
  delete req._passport.user;
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/");
});
```

And calling it in **Client Side > `App.js`** using this code:

```
  const {user} = useContext(Context);
  const { dispatch } = useContext(Context);
  const [userr, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/googleLogin/success", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
          console.log(response)
          throw new Error("authentication has been failed!");
        })
        .then((resObject) => {
          setUser(resObject.user)
          dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
          if(resObject.user.email){
            dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: resObject.user });
          }else{
            dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);
```

The issue is that `console.log("CURRNT USER: ", user);` keeps running nonstop, and I keep getting the user info in console once and once again.

I call Logout using this code:

```
const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  };
```

I don't know what i'm missing!

Comment: Can yous hold what you in `LOGOUT` type action handler?

Comment: `const Reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
}
}
export default Reducer;`